Building up "Grading System" of a school by using "switch" control statement
I'm a new learner in my coding journey. I was trying to build up a system that can collect numbers and show the Grade according to every individual number. I'm doing it in Code::Blocks. But the system is not working. And also giving input of every individual number is really very time consuming and tough to complete.I tried this code below-->
#include<stdio.h>
 int main()
 
{ 
int num; 
printf("Enter any number : ");
scanf("%d",&num);

switch(a)
{
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
case 9:
case 10:
case 11:
case 12:
case 13:
case 14:
case 15:
case 16:
case 17:
case 18:
case 19:
case 20:
case 21:
case 22:
case 23:
case 24:
case 25:
case 26:
case 27:
case 28:
case 29:
case 30:
case 31:
case 32:
    printf("F");
    break;

case 33:
case 34:
case 35:
case 36:
case 37:
case 38:
case 39:
    printf("D");
    break;

case 40:
case 41:
case 42:
case 43:
case 44:
case 45:
case 46:
case 47:
case 48:
case 49:
    printf("C");
    break;

case 50:
case 51:
case 52:
case 53:
case 54:
case 55:
case 56:
case 57:
case 58:
case 59:
    print("B");
    break;

case 60:
case 61:
case 62:
case 63:
case 64:
case 65:
case 66:
case 67:
case 68:
case 69:
    printf("A-");
    break;

case 70:
case 71:
case 72:
case 73:
case 74:
case 75:
case 76:
case 77:
case 78:
case 79:
    printf("A");
    break;

case 80:
case 81:
case 82:
case 83:
case 84:
case 85:
case 86:
case 87:
case 88:
case 89:
case 90:
case 91:
case 92:
case 93:
case 94:
case 95:
case 96:
case 97:
case 98:
case 99:
case 100:
    printf("A+");
    break;

default:
    printf("Not valid");
}

}

I was expecting that if i entered any number , the system will show me the Grade of that individual number.

This code shouldn't even compile. The name of the variable is num, but you used switch(a) instead of switch(num)

This isn't an appropriate use for switch(). use if (num <= 32) { ... } else if (num <= 39) { ... } and so on

Other than the above typo, I don't see any reason why the code wouldn't work. What are you getting instead of the expected result?

Also the typo print("B"); instead of printf("B"). The code doesn't compile, so it can't work.

When you are given a number and are asked to translate it to a letter in your head, are you going to ask yourself "Is the number 1? Is it 2? Is it 3?...." etc? No, you will ask yourself - in which range is it. Now you should be translating the same logic into your program.

You need to post the actual code that's giving you a problem, not retype it, since you're introducing new errors and may be hiding the original errors.

Welcome to the world of coding! If you find the example "very time consuming and tough to complete" then you may be in for a disappointment, when you throw away hours of work after taking a wrong turn :) In this case, consider using the much easier and quicker if ... else if.

@WeatherVane A true programmer would write  script to generate this list of cases automatically :D

You forgot to mention a few very important things. What does not work? If that is your exact real code (which it definitely should be!) then you cannot even run your program because the compiler will print some error messages. In that case it is important to show these messages (exact and complete) in your question. If this code is just some random alternation of your code (which makes it rather useless) but your real code compiles fine, then you need to tell us what "But the system is not working." means. Does it crash? Does it burn your PC? Does it just terminate without any output?

great choice C is a great language to learn.
First of all, there’s an error on line 79. You should use printf instead of print.
Secondly, the number you get with the scanf is stored in the num variable. However, you're trying to use the switch statement on the A variable, which is not defined and doesn't contain your value. You should use your switch statement with the num variable instead.
To have a more concise code you should try using if statement like this:
if(num > = 32) { printf("F"); } else if ...

